# Deploy lambda function on aws-pulumi

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I'm trying to deploy a lambda Function on my AWS account, that zips a file that is uploaded into "lambda-bucket-in" onto a bucket "lambda-bucket-out". The example I'm trying to follow is [this](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/easy-serverless-apps-and-infrastructure-real-events-real-code/) one, specifically the **second** way (the first does its job properly).

My pulumi code is the following one:

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";


const tpsReports = new aws.s3.Bucket("lambda-bucket-in");
const tpsZips = new aws.s3.Bucket("lambda-bucket-out");


// First, create some IAM machinery:
const zipFuncRole = new aws.iam.Role("zipTpsReportsFuncRole", {
    assumeRolePolicy: {
       Version: "2012-10-17",
       Statement: [{
          Action: "sts:AssumeRole",
          Principal: {
             Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          },
          Effect: "Allow",
          Sid: "",
       }],
    },
 });
 new aws.iam.RolePolicyAttachment("zipTpsReportsFuncRoleAttach", {
    role: zipFuncRole,
    policyArn: aws.iam.ManagedPolicy.AWSLambdaExecute,
 });
 
 // Next, create the Lambda function itself:
 const zipFunc = new aws.lambda.Function("zipTpsReportsFunc", {
    environment: {
       variables: {
          "TPS_ZIP_BUCKET": tpsZips.bucket,
       },
    },
    code: new pulumi.asset.AssetArchive({
       ".": new pulumi.asset.FileArchive("app"),
    }),
    runtime: "nodejs12.x",
    role: zipFuncRole.arn,
 });
 
 // Finally, register the Lambda to fire when a new TPS report arrives:
 tpsReports.onObjectCreated("zipTpsReports", zipFunc);
```

While "app" file, with the lambda function is:

```
   const AdmZip = require("adm-zip");
   const s3 = new aws.sdk.S3();
   for (const rec of e.Records || []) {
      const zip = new AdmZip();
      const [ buck, key ] = [ rec.s3.bucket.name, rec.s3.object.key ];
      console.log(`Zipping ${buck}/${key} into ${tpsZips.bucket.get()}/${key}.zip`);
      const data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: buck, Key: key }).promise);
      zip.addFile(key, data.Body);
      await s3.putObject({
         Bucket: tpsZips.bucket.get(),
         Key: `${key}.zip`,
         Body: zip.toBuffer(),
      }).promise();
   }
```

While running pulumi with the command `pulumi up --yes`, and after inserting the password, it returns:

```
Previewing update (my-lambda):
     Type                                  Name                         Plan       Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack                   bucket-my-lambda-my-lambda   create     1 error; 48 messages
 +   ├─ aws:s3:Bucket                      lambda-bucket-out            create     
 +   ├─ aws:s3:Bucket                      lambda-bucket-in             create     
 +   │  ├─ aws:s3:BucketEventSubscription  zipTpsReports                create     
 +   │  └─ aws:s3:BucketNotification       zipTpsReports                create     
 +   ├─ aws:iam:Role                       zipTpsReportsFuncRole        create     
 +   └─ aws:iam:RolePolicyAttachment       zipTpsReportsFuncRoleAttach  create     
 
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (bucket-my-lambda-my-lambda):
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
        at deserializeProperty (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:472:48)
        at Object.deserializeProperties (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:126:24)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:524:43
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:21:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:17:12)
        at resolveOutputs (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:519:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:321:19)
        at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
        at deserializeProperty (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:472:48)
        at Object.deserializeProperties (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:126:24)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:524:43
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:21:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:17:12)
        at resolveOutputs (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:519:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:321:19)
        at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
 
    unhandled rejection: CONTEXT(1251): monitor.registerResource(resource:zipTpsReports[aws:lambda/permission:Permission])-initial
    STACK_TRACE:
    Error:
        at Object.debuggablePromise (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/debuggable.js:69:75)
        at runAsyncResourceOp (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:634:75)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:257:9)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:21:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:17:12)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:219:63
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    unhandled rejection: CONTEXT(1251): monitor.registerResource(resource:zipTpsReports[aws:lambda/permission:Permission])-initial
    STACK_TRACE:
    Error:
        at Object.debuggablePromise (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/debuggable.js:69:75)
        at runAsyncResourceOp (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:634:75)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:257:9)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:21:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:17:12)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:219:63
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
 
    error: Running program '/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda' failed with an unhandled exception:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
        at deserializeProperty (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:472:48)
        at Object.deserializeProperties (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/rpc.js:126:24)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:524:43
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:21:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:17:12)
        at resolveOutputs (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:519:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrea/Piratech/pulumi/bucket-my-lambda/node_modules/@pulumi/pulumi/runtime/resource.js:321:19)
        at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, and what does it stand for?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks similar to this issue (not resolved yet): https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/5832